# Call a function every time a semicolon is typed in Tkinter Entry Widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working a TCP chatroom with GUI(tkinter) and I don't want to take any ':' in my message input from user.

So I decided that every time a user types a ':' in entry box, a function would be called and ':' will be deleted. But it happens that first the function is called, the last character is deleted then ':' is typed into the Entry box.

Here is my code:

```
#CODE OMITTED

def typing_error():
    temp_text = message_entry.get()[:-1]
    message_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    message_entry.insert(0, temp_text)
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Semicolon(:) is not allowed")

# Text box to send message
message_entry = tk.Entry(root, bg='grey')
message_entry.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
message_entry.bind(':', lambda x: typing_error())

#CODE OMITTED
```

**This is before typing ':'**

[image]

**After typing ':'**

[image]

**After parsing the error message**

[image]

Well I know why it is happening, but can't figure out how to solve it. please help me.

Comment: If I am right, you can still just paste text with colons in it into the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply return `"break"` to discard it in the bind callback:

```py
def typing_error(event):
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Semicolon(:) is not allowed")
    return "break"

...

message_entry.bind(':', typing_error)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I was using ```lambda``` without any reason and I didn't know that ```"break"``` would stop the ongoing function

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to show the error message first then delete the semi colon.

```
def typing_error():
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Semicolon(:) is not allowed")
    message_entry.delete("end-2c")

message_entry = tk.Entry(root, bg='grey')
message_entry.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
message_entry.bind(':', typing_error)
```

Comment: No that is  not the problem. I tried this and it deletes the first character of the box, but semicolon is there. Actually the function is called first then semicolon is inserted into the text box. I want to insert semicolon to the text box first then call the function.

Comment: @SatyajitSatapatathy Instead of making a temp variable and deleting the entire text. Just delete the last character which obviously is going to be the ':'. But before that show the error message. I'll edit the code be sure to check.

Comment: It is now giving error that ```"end-2c"``` is bad gateway

Comment: @SatyajitSatapatathy Try `len(message_entry.get()) - 1` instead of `'end-2c'`

Comment: @SatyajitSatapatathy I just noticed the way you used bind is prone to bugs, change it to `message_entry.bind(":", typing_error)`.